# ninject conventions multiple binding constructor injection

Tags: c#, ninject

so I'm having an issue with getting all instances of classes that implement a generic interface to come through in my constructor

I am using

```
kernel.Bind(x => x.FromThisAssembly().SelectAllClasses()
                  .InheritedFrom(typeof(IRepository<>)).BindAllInterfaces());
```

I have a test that passes when I ask for a specific repository

```
var booking = kernel.Get<BookingRepository>();
Assert.IsNotNull(booking);
```

but I have created a class that takes

```
ICollection<IRepository<EntityBase>> repositories,
```

where entitybase is an abstract class that all my entities inherit from and I don't get anything back and the test

```
var rep = kernel.GetAll<IRepository<EntityBase>>();
```

doesn't contain anything when I assert that it contains something using .Any()

if I manually add a mapping

```
kernel.Bind<IRepository<EntityBase>>().To<BookingRepository>();
```

then this would be injected into the collection and would work but I wanted to save myself the hassle of remembering to add a mapping when I create a new repository and just have them bound when the application starts.

Am I able to get all the repositories injected into the constructor using

```
ICollection<IRepository<EntityBase>>
```

Comment: Is it always true that IRepository<Entity> is assignable to IRepository<EntityBase>?

Comment: yeah, I have an entity type and a valuetype type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to create your own logic to define which types to bind to:

```
kernel.Bind(x => x.FromThisAssembly()
    .SelectAllClasses()
    .InheritedFrom(typeof(IRepository<>))
    .BindSelection(this.SelectDefaultInterfaceAndRepositoryBaseInterface));

private IEnumerable<Type> SelectDefaultInterfaceAndRepositoryBaseInterface(
    Type t,
    IEnumerable<Type> baseTypes)
{
    yield return baseTypes.Single(x => 
                                   x.IsGenericType
                                   && x.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IRepository<>));

    yield return typeof(IRepository<EntityBase>);
}
```

I have run the code and ItWorksTM (including ctor-injection of `ICollection<IRepository<EntityBase>>`)

Comment: Thanks, that worked perfectly, only wished I'd asked this question a few days sooner rather than wasting time googling for an answer